# Can I add a character to the formula being written to a cell?

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I am calculating delta and writing it to a cell. But I need to add % to the end of the formula in the write method.

I have tried various methods to add that character but unable to do it.

```
#Calculate Delta
worksheet1.write(configRow + 1, configCol + 3, "=((C{}-D{})/D{})".format(configRow + 2, configRow + 2, configRow + 2))

#Perform Conditional Formatting
worksheet1.conditional_format('E{}'.format(configRow + 2), {'type': 'cell',
                                                            'criteria': 'between',
                                                            'minimum': -3,
                                                            'maximum': 3,
                                                            'format':   format_values5})
```

With the above code I am able to write a number to a cell and format it based on certain criteria. 
Eg: E23 contains 1.00056

I need a result like this, which contains % at the end:
1.00056 %

Comment: Does it work with `'criteria': '%'` ?

Comment: No, criteria defines only the condition on which the cell formatting  is made. My question is to know how to add '%' at the end of the value thats calculated in the write method.

Comment: In the write method:
```
worksheet1.write(configRow + 1, configCol + 3, "=((C{}-D{})/D{})"
```
Can I somehow add the "%" character to the end of the calculated value?

Comment: If you want the number to show up as a percentage you need to divide it by 100 and add a number format: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#format-set-num-format. In this case the number format `%` would probably be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, I did the same.

Answer (score 1):

What I did is:

```
cell_format01 = workbook.add_format({
        'align': 'center',
        'valign': 'vcenter',
        'border': 1
        })
    cell_format01.set_num_format('0.00%')
worksheet1.write(configRow + 1, configCol + 3, "=((C{}-D{})/D{})".format(configRow + 2, configRow + 2, configRow + 2), cell_format01)
```

So, the cell_formt01 has the set_num_format where I am defining the format type. So, all the values written using write() method will be formatted in the cell_formt01 manner.